# How to handle image output from cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsimage

I have a question about the image output of a cocoa app. For the following code will create 
different sized images(2x or 1x depending on the display) in retina displays and non retina displays. But I want the output image is 225x300 in every situations.

```
NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
[image setScalesWhenResized:YES];
[image setSize:NSMakeSize(225, 300)];
[[image TIFFRepresentation]writeToURL:exportFileURL options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
```

My question is how to handle this correctly.

Comment: is the above code exactly what you are using or is a NSView or child involved?

Comment: no child views are involved. But nsview has a superview. the setSize method is different I use a proportional scaling method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are writing the image from an `NSView` according to your comment, you'll need to properly support hi resolution retina displays. If the view is displayed on a retina display, you may want to adjust for scaling. See [Apples Documentation on this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/APIs/APIs.html). You will have to convertFrom/ToBacking accordingly.